# Are sharedHTTPCookieStorage cookies stored locally in IOS app?

Tags: ios, cookies

I'm currently developing an app containing login. I saved my authtoken in cookie. I completely closed my IOS app without signing out. When I opened the same, the further requests that I make contains my authtoken. I have doubt about where the cookies that I got from 
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies],
 are stored. I checked if Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies contains, but it doesn't contain authtoken. Are those cookies stored locally. if yes, where?

Answer (score 2):

NSHttpCookieStorage loses persistance when you don't set the expiration time for cookies. If you set the expiration time your cookies will persist when you app exits.